# Oracle trigger insert to other table then modify the original table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, insert

I have theses two tables:

```
TABLE ASSET_ENTRY_NOTE (
  ID                  NUMBER         NOT NULL, --PK
  ASSETMDL_ID         NUMBER         NOT NULL, --FK
  DEPT_ID             NUMBER         NOT NULL, --FK
  LOCATION            NVARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  ASSET_ID            NUMBER,                  --FK TO ASSETS
  ACCOUNT_ID          NUMBER         NOT NULL, --FK
  TOTAL_DPRC_DURATION FLOAT(126)     NOT NULL,
  TOTAL_PROD_HRS      FLOAT(126),
  AMORTIZATION_PRCNTG FLOAT(126),
  ACQUIRE_DATE        DATE           NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION         NVARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
  APPRFLAG            NUMBER         DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  WRK_HRS             FLOAT(126),

)

TABLE ASSETS (
 ID                   NUMBER         NOT NULL, --PK
 ASSETMDL_ID          NUMBER         NOT NULL, --FK
 DEPT_ID              NUMBER         NOT NULL,
 LOCATION             NVARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL, --FK
 ACCOUNT_ID           NUMBER         NOT NULL,
 ACQUIRE_DATE         DATE           NOT NULL,
 TOTAL_DPRC_DURATION  FLOAT(126),
 BALANCE_CLOSING_DATE DATE,
 SELL_VAL             FLOAT(126),
 RPLCMNT_DISCOUNT     FLOAT(126),
 DESCRIPTION          NVARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
)
```

Note that there's a one to one relationship between the two tables (i.e. `ASSET_ENTRY_NOTE.ASSET_ID` is Unique.
When the `ASSETS_ENTRY_NOTE.APPRFLAG` is updated to 1 I have this trigger that:

1. gets a new primary key sequence for the `ASSETS` table.
2. insert data from `ASSETS_ENTRY_NOTE` to `ASSETS`.
3. updates the column `ASSETS_ENTRY_NOTE.ASSET_ID` to the same value as the primary key value on the sequence.

This is the latest try for my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ENTRYNT_ASSET_TRIG
after UPDATE OF APPRFLAG ON ASSET_ENTRY_NOTE
  for each row
  when (new.apprflag = 1)
declare
   v_asset_id number;
BEGIN
 SELECT assets_PK_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO v_asset_id   
  FROM DUAL d;

 insert into assets (ID,
                                    assets.assetmdl_id,
                                    assets.dept_id,
                                    assets.location,
                                    assets.account_id,
                                    assets.acquire_date,
                                    assets.total_dprc_duration,
                                    assets.description
                                    )

                           values (v_asset_id,
                                   assetmdl_id,
                                   dept_id,
                                   location,
                                   account_id,
                                   acquire_date,
                                   total_dprc_duration,
                                   description
                                   );

 update ASSET_ENTRY_NOTE set asset_id = v_asset_id where ;
END;
```

The thing is, I know that `ASSET_ENTRY_NOTE` is a mutating table and the last `UPDATE` statement is not allowed here, But nothing else is working for me.
What I've already tried:

1. creating a statement-level trigger to update one value only.
2. using `before` instead of `after` but that's incorrect because I need the values just to insert into the `ASSETS`.
3. using a cursor to go through each value changed but I had exact fetch error.
4. creating a procedure that handles inserting and updating.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design seems quite strange to me, but to answer the question about the trigger:

To change the asset_entry_note row in the trigger, you need a `before update` trigger. In there you can just assign the value to the `asset_id` column.

Your `insert` statement is also wrong. You can table-qualify column names in the column list of an `insert` statement. And the `values` clause needs to use the values from the inserted row. You are referencing the target table's columns which is not allowed).

You also don't need a `select` statement to obtain the sequence value.

Putting all that together, your trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ENTRYNT_ASSET_TRIG
BEFORE UPDATE OF APPRFLAG ON ASSET_ENTRY_NOTE
  for each row
  when (new.apprflag = 1)
declare
   v_asset_id number;
BEGIN
  v_asset_id := assets_PK_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

  insert into assets 
    (ID,
     assetmdl_id,
     dept_id,
     location,
     account_id,
     acquire_date,
     total_dprc_duration,
     description)
   values 
     (v_asset_id,
      new.assetmdl_id, -- reference the inserted row here!
      new.dept_id,
      new.location,
      new.account_id,
      new.acquire_date,
      new.total_dprc_duration,
      new.description);

  new.asset_id := v_asset_id;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added the answer as soon as I've found it and here you are, thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the design of the application to have only one table with sign to indicate the membership of a particular entity.

Another way is to create 'after statement' trigger to update all affected rows in ASSET_ENTRY_NOTE with proper values. These rows is to be collected in, for example, package collection in row-level trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and it worked:

1. changed to `before`.
2. edited the update statement to an assignment of new so that the last line would become `:new.asset_id := v_asset_id ;`